# Build a dotnet core app with jenkins inside a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, asp.net-core

I have a dotnet core application that has a dockerfile in it. And I have a jenkins setup running inside a docker container. I have created a build job for the dotnet core app using the docker build command passing required parameters as below

```
docker build -t ghkonline:${build_version} [dir_to_dockerfile_in_repo]
```

Running the build gives below error
`17:03:28 /tmp/jenkins7957920034154044900.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins7957920034154044900.sh: docker: not found
17:03:28 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

Comment: Is the Docker daemon running? The `docker build` command can’t execute if the Docker daemon hasn’t been started. `sudo systemctl start docker` may do the trick.

Comment: Can a docker container run without the deamon? As the jenkins is running inside a container.

Comment: No, Docker cannot run with the Docker daemon running (dockerd). Good news is that you are *not* limited to one running process in a container. Check out the Docker documentation for detailed help. [Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) is a good first step.